# Why is assertThat(map1, sameInstance(map2)) not allowed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

With the new Assert grammar, when testing for identity, one would write

```
Assert.assertThat(obj1, CoreMatchers.sameInstance(obj2))
```

instead of

```
Assert.assertSame(obj1, obj2)
```

I am trying assert the identity of a map. So I write

```
Assert.assertThat(map1, CoreMatchers.sameInstance(map2))
```

where map is of type `HashMap<String,String>`
But my tests fail at compile time:

```
Error:(33, 9) error: no suitable method found for assertThat(Map,Matcher<Map<String,String>>)
method Assert.<T#1>assertThat(String,T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method Assert.<T#2>assertThat(T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
(argument mismatch; Matcher<Map<String,String>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super Map>))
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>assertThat(String,T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>assertThat(T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>)
Error:(33) error: no suitable method found for assertThat(Map,Matcher<Map<String,String>>)
```

Why can't JUnit (or Hamcrest) figure out which matcher to use?

Comment: Is `map1` a raw `Map` or a `Map<String, String>`? If it's a raw `Map`, it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Fail at runtime? That looks like a compile-time error. How are `map1` and `map2` declared?

Comment: Oops! It fails at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this had nothing to do with asserting the identity of the map - the code was correct - but it does have something to do with generics.

The class I was trying to test looked something like this:

```
public class Response<T>{
    public final Map<String, String> map;
    public final T data;
}
```

However, the test was written like this:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Object data = new Object();
    Response target = new Response<>(map, data);
    assertThat(target.map, sameInstance(map));
    assertThat(target.data, sameInstance(data));
}
```

The compilation error is actually at the last line, because T is unknown `(<?>)` to the compiler, it couldn't find an appropriate matcher. I fixed the test by declaring the raw type.

```
@Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Object data = new Object();
    Response<Object> target = new Response<>(map, data);
    assertThat(target.map, sameInstance(map));
    assertThat(target.data, sameInstance(data));
}
```

But I find it odd why the compiler complains about the previous line...

Comment: If you use a raw `Response`, its instance variables are also raw types, even if the `Response`'s type parameters aren't involved. `target.map` is raw if `target` is.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks for the insights!